# Splitting a String in Pandas DF and Adding a Column with the Resulting List of Values

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, split

I am trying to split a string in a Pandas DF and add the resulting list as a new column.  For example the string:

```
"A;B;C;D"
```

Would be stored in a new column as:

```
['A','B','C','D']
```

Currently trying this code:

```
df['SplitList'] = [re.split(";",i) for i in df['List']]
```

But getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 171, in split
return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Cool, let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: I added the error I was getting for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas, the preferred way would be to use str methods

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["A;B;C;D"]})
df['new'] = df['col'].str.split(';')

    col     new
0   A;B;C;D [A, B, C, D]
```